# Annoyance with always in Present Simple?

Tags: tenses

I have to fill the gap in the sentence:

> Why do you ......... leave the light on when you go out of the room?
> You wait till you start paying the electricity bill!

Key says it must be filled with "always" but it must be Present Continuous then (accordingly to the rule in that unit: annoying/amusing habits + "always" -> Present Continuous).

Why is it Present Simple there?

(From "Destination C1 & C2", 2008. Unit 1, Exercise B. 1)

Comment: Because the rules you are citing are nonsense. There is no "must be" involved with the progressive construction.  There is no "Must" involved with the use of the continuous construction (though there are some "Must Nots"). By the way, the use of school terms like "Present Simple" marks the questioner as an English learner; these are not terms used by linguists.

Comment: Present Continuous *Why **are you always leaving** the light on when you go out of the room?* isn't idiomatic in "mainstream English" - it's "Indian English", and would normally be recognised as such by most native Anglophones.

Comment: I voted to close as opinion based.  When you're communicating with people, you may choose either one.  To get through your class, you'll need to ask your instructor what their thinking is.

Answer (score 1):

The present simple for non-stative verbs generally has a habitual meaning. Thus it already refers to ongoing action and thus is not in conflict with adverbs like "always".

For example, these are acceptable sentences in English:

- "Every morning I go for a run".
- "I always drink my coffee with sugar".

See the Uses section of this wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_present

However, you can also use the present continuous. The choice between the two boils down to whether you are stressing the mere repetition of an act, or the progression of the act in its repetition. These illustrate the difference:

- "Why do you always eat candy?" -- stresses repeatedly engaging in and completing the act of eating candy. The amount of time it takes is irrelevant. You might say this if you think someone had a candy addiction.
- "Why are you always eating candy?" -- stresses being in the process of eating candy and doing it frequently. You might say this if you keep entering a room and finding someone eating candy. The concern is not the repetition so much as the fact that candy eating is happening a lot.

Comment: Another example from the other book: "She's always interrupting me!". Interrupting seems to be a momentary action.

Comment: @Zefir It's about perspective and which aspect of the action you are stressing. The distinction between punctual and ongoing events is purely linguistic and has nothing to do with the nature of the events themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving a room is probably best regarded as a punctive/punctual act (ie taking negligible time, regarded as an instant).

'Leave' as used here picks up the punctive aspect (you 'leave the light on' the moment you step out of the room, almost a momentary non-act).

- *She never leaves the tap dripping.*
- *She never left the tap dripping* is equally possible.

Compare

- *He always leaves/parks the car on the drive.*

And compare the related usage

- *He always leaves a tip for the waiter.*

(The 'leaving' is over in a moment, the 'left on the table' state a few seconds longer!)

Comment: Another example from the other book: "She's always interrupting me!". It's momentary, isn't it?

Comment: Each occasion is 'momentary' (although the notion of a single point in time remains in the realm of philosophy). The whole is iterative.